# OP-Amp 564 Output Shutdown

Tags: operational-amplifier, pulldown

I need to build a controllable output shutdown for the OPA 564 so I can force the amp to shut down. The solution in the datasheet uses an optocoupler but I rather use it with some pull-down resistor. My build uses dual-supply with +/- 6,2 V.
In this link you have the datasheet of OP 564: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa564.pdf

[image]
Could this be a solution?
[image]

Comment: How about an analog Mux? MC4053?

Comment: The datasheet says above that picture, `... to shut down the OPA564 the voltage level of the logic signal must be level-shifted by some means.` Do you believe a pull-down resistor will accomplish this?

Comment: So how can I do this in the simplest way?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work (one zener and one resistor):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnXGST.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Plz see the new image where i put the layout

Comment: Can i level shift the signal with a Voltage divider with 2 resistors?

Comment: No that won't work, there is already a pullup resistor inside the chip (the nominal 100K I show above). The absolute simplest way is to use a CD4053 as @analogsystemsrf suggests in a comment, only a  single component (because it has built-in level shifting).

Comment: So how do I do it?

Comment: 4053? Power it from +/-6.2, make sure the logic '1' input is more than 0.7 * 6.2 = 4.3V and connect a switch of the 4503 (your choice of N.O. or N.C.) between the E/bS input to -6.2V.

Comment: You could also power it from +5/-6.2V which might be better for power consumption with digital input high.

Comment: Plz check this possible solution i got in this page: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa182/sbaa182.pdf

Comment: I don't think your added diagram will work unless Vss = 0V.

Comment: the second image

Comment: Thx for the help but I use PNP transistor to level shift the value